# Form validation using data attribute not grabbing all data

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form that I am trying to validate. I have been using the `id` and the `class` to get the element but I would like to be able to get everything in one pass through. The reason for using the class attribute for one section and not another is because I allow the user to add additional address information. I have posted all the code below.

```
<form role='form' id='application-form'>
    <div class='h2div'><h2 data-toggle='#general-information' data-active='general-information'>General Information</h2></div>
    <div class='appdiv' id='general-information'>
        <div class='form-group row'>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
                <label class='control-label'>First Name<span class='req'> *</span></label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control not-empty first_name' id='first_name' value="<?=$first_name?>" data-name='first_name'/>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
                <label class='control-label'>Middle Name</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control middle_name' id='middle_name' value="<?=$middle_name?>" data-name='middle_name'/>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
                <label class='control-label'>Last Name<span class='req'> *</span></label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control not-empty last_name' id='last_name' value="<?=$last_name?>" data-name='last_name'/>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
                <label class='control-label'>Suffix</label>
                <input type='text' class='form-control suffix' id='suffix' placeholder='e.x. Jr., Sr., ...' value="<?=$suffix?>" data-name='suffix'/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='h2div'><h2 data-toggle='#address-records' data-active='address-records'>Address Records</h2></div>
    <div class='appdiv' id='address-records'>
        <div class='address-form'>
            <div class='form-group row'>
                <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
                    <label class='control-label'>City<span class='req'> *</span></label>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control city not-empty' placeholder='city' data-name="city"/>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
                    <label class='control-label'>State<span class='req'> *</span></label>
                    <select class='form-control state not-empty' data-name="state">
                        <option value="" selected>-- State --</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
                    <label class='control-label'>Zip Code<span class='req'> *</span></label>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control zip not-empty' placeholder='#####' data-name="zip"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group row'>
            <div class='col-md-12'>
                <a href="" id="add_address">Add Another Address</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the validation script

```
 var sections = ["general-information", "address-records", "employment-history", "driving-experience", "military-experience", "self-identification", "psp-notice", "eva-section"]; //array that houses the id tags of the application sections
$('#application-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //stop the form from the default submission
    var application_info = new Object(); //start the application form Object
    //run through each section and gather info 
    for(var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++){
        application_info[sections[i]] = new Object(); //create a new object for each section
        //traverse each select by form control 
        $("#"+sections[i]).find(".form-control").map(function (index, element){
            $(element).each(function (index){
                //application_info 
                application_info[sections[i]][$(element).data('name')] = $('.'+$(element).data('name')).eq(index).val();
            });
        }).get();
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '../assets/server/application_process.php',
        type : 'post',
        data : application_info,
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success : function (data){
        }
    });
});
```

I would like to be able to keep the same functionality and allow the script to build one large object. Please let me know if more information is needed. I will provide as much as possible.

Comment: what is `section` in `sections.length` ? What it defines?

Comment: it is the id of each section that holds the input elements, I have edited

Comment: basically i see no fault if you put the whole form data together into one object and then send thru ajax it to server. Just place some `console.log/console.dir` in `map/each` function to trace in js console if you do everything right (get corresponding fields). Good luck!

Comment: i get the proper data just not the extra data from the additional form elements that are added when the form address button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> not the extra data from the additional form elements that are added when the form address button is clicked

Explain more.

- What data are added (how data are formed on server)?
- How are these data fetched ?
- how data are appended to form?
- What the form looks like right after appending additional data (in web debugger)?
- Seems in `success : function (data){
      }` you do nothing...

### Update

1. Seems like you need to query in google: 'jquery reinit dom'
2. Here goes the distilled question like yours: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/reinitialize-document-ready-after-ajax-and-jquery
3. And the link to jquery method: http://api.jquery.com/live/ that would *Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, **now and in the future***
4. The `live()` method is depricated, so *Use `.on()` to attach event handlers* : http://api.jquery.com/on/
5. Code:

   $('#application-form').submit(function(e){...

   try to turn to:

   $('#application-form').on('submit', function(e){ ...